# Pairwise distances between rows with matching id

Tags: python, mysql

I have a database with multiple tables that I want to update based on pairwise distances only between the same ids. Example: calculate pairwise distances between id 1 (3 rows), and id 3 (2 rows).and then update the table by removing the row where id is same and pairwise distance is less than 25% (i.e., 75% similar).

```
Table1

S.no id class info
   1  1 a     kkkkkkkkkkllmmhhbbddd
   2  1 a     kkkkkkkkkkllhhhhbbddd
   3  1 b     kkkkkkkkkkllhhhhbbddd
   4  2 b     kkkkkkkkkkllhhhhbbddd
   5  3 a     kkkkkkkkhhbbddd
   6  3 a     kkkkkkkkhhbbdddbbdddd
```

This is what I tried

```
   curs = conn.cursor()
   path = '/my/path/to/folder'
   id=[]
   class=[]
   info=[]
   count=[]
   curs.execute("""select id, class, info, count(class) AS co from `Table1` group by id having co > 1""")
   result = curs.fetchall()
   print(result)
   for c1, c2, c3, c4 in result:
      id.append(c1)
      class.append(c2)
      info.appened(c3)
      count.appened(c4)
      if(id==id):
          dist = pdist(row('info'), row('info'))
          print(dist)
   curs.close()
   conn.close()
```

Comment: Note that excluding from the GROUP BY any non-aggregated columns appearing in the SELECT is just asking for trouble - especially where you are not grouping on the PK

Comment: seems like you need to not group by, and do an initial pass through the results grouping them into arrays by id so you can process one id at a time.  Then you need to figure out what you want to do in all possible cases (e.g. 4 rows for an id A,B,C,D where (A,B), (B,C), (C,D) are <25)